# 'SQLSTATE 57017' (Character Conversion Problem)for SQL UDF java program on the iSeries

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange

I followed the instructions at http://www.itjungle.com/mpo/mpo100903-story01.html

The UDF looks like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION re_Test(input VARCHAR(500),
                              regex VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS INTEGER
EXTERNAL NAME 'UDFs.re_Test'
LANGUAGE Java
PARAMETER STYLE Java
FENCED
NO SQL
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
SCRATCHPAD
DETERMINISTIC
```

And the java method in UDFsthat is being called looks like this

```
  public static int re_Test(String input, 
                            String regex) throws Exception {
    // returns number of occurrences
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(input);

    int noFound=0;

    while (matcher.find())
        noFound++;

    return noFound;
  }
```

If I run the function from SquirrelSQL

```
select re_test('abcdeab','ab') from sysibm/sysdummy1
```

It works fine, however, if I run **STRSQL** from the AS/400 5020 console I get this error in the job log `SQLSTATE 57017`

I am able to fix this problem by running CHGJOB and entering 37 instead of 65535 in the CCSID field.

This is hardly desirable as I would need to do this everytime I logged on.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your user profile is probably set with `CCSID(*SYSVAL)` which means your job will be started based on the system value `QCCSID`.

Consider changing your user profile to `CCSID(37)`.

Comment: What if other users use the function?  What if an RPGLE program uses the function?  This is a little risky